# scandir filter by type S_ISDIR

Tags: c, linux, filter, directory, scandir

I am trying to create a scandir filter so I can get the list of directories. This way regular fyles and links are obviated.

```
int directoryFilter(const struct dirent *entry){
    struct stat st;
    stat(entry->d_name,&st);
    if(S_ISDIR(st.st_mode))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

It works, compiles and run fine. But if I do the same execution twice I just get the `.` and `..` directories.

Any clue about why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

The directories `.` and `..` are special entries always present in every directory. Since they start with dot, they are deemed hidden by most tools, but you still can see them if you type in the terminal `ls -a`.

You probably already know what they do:

- `..` is a link to the previous directory (except it `/`, where it points to `/` itself), so that opening the file `../file_in_parent_directory` works.
- `.` is a link to current directory, so that executing a script in current directory can be done by calling it via `./script.sh`.

If you don't want for hidden directories like these to show up in your list, you must also filter out every directory that starts with dot (`.`). If don't want just these two, you must explicitly filter them out.

Comment: Ok. When i run the program the output is right. I get all the directories but if  I close it and run it again I just get the `.` and `..` directories. Any clue about this bug?

Comment: I am not sure what you meant. What changed from one execution to another? Did you run your program from the same directory?

Comment: When I run it ther first time I get all the directories in the path but if i run it twice in the same path I just get the directories `.` `..`.

Comment: If you go to the path and type `ls -a`, is there anything in the directory? There can be only two things that happened: either the directory contents is no longer there, because it was moved or erased, or you didn't make the exact same execution you did before: you may have used a different binary, or executed from a different directory, or didn't use the same path, or something else that affected the execution.

Comment: yes, there are other directories and files. I am using code::blocks to run it so I don't know why this is happening.